# How to implement Google Analytics Enhanced Ecommerce on server-side?

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, enhanced-ecommerce

I'm working on GA in my project. I want to send data about transactions to GA from back-end, and here is a problem. I use `"@nuxtjs/google-analytics": "^2.2.0"`, but it works only from front-end.

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/integrating-with-analytics#sample_application) I have found about `Server-side analytics collection`, but there where only primitive actions (Event category, Event action, Event label, Event value). As I said, I'm working with Enhanced Ecommerce, so, I need actions like `addProduct`, `addAction` and so on.

Is it possible to do **such** server-side GA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to implement using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/universal-analytics#event-tracking) package.